# "Connecting to database specified by database.yml" in Rails production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ubuntu

I've deployed a Rails 3 app on Ubuntu server and when I open the app in the browser, there's the **500 error** screen and in the logs (`production.log`) I see following:

```
...
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

The set up in the `database.yml` file should be correct:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: myapp_production
  username: rails
  password: mypass
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306  
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

when I try to log in to `mysql` with the credentials above:

```
mysql -u rails -p
```

I am successfully authenticated.

The server is from DigitalOcean.

Any tips why I'm seeing this error message?

Thank you!

Comment: hi, sorry for posting this comment here, but could you view my question about tp link router. It seems that you had a problem like I have now http://superuser.com/questions/441672/after-set-up-local-network-through-router-internet-is-slow

Answer (score 1):

SSH into the server, navigate to the root folder of the Rails app, and run `rails console production`.
It's usually due to a syntax error in your app - in a model, initializer, or controller.  Rails will attempt booting the console for the production environment. If there is a syntax error, this will be caught here and you will get an error message telling you exactly where to look to fix the error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. When I run `rails console production`, I get `Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.12)` - so no error message

Comment: Try this code `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` in rails production console to check if its connecting to db correctly.